# Unrecognized service in Openvpn templatized systemd jobs

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I am installing an OpenVPN server in a PC with Ubuntu 14.04 as the operating system by following the very complete guide that is located at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html#openvpn-simple-client-configuration.

So far I have been following all the steps with no problem but when I have to launch the server itself it says that "Be aware that the "service openvpn start" is not starting your openvpn you just defined. Openvpn uses templatized systemd jobs, openvpn@CONFIGFILENAME. So if for example your configuration file is "server.conf" your service is called openvpn@server. ".

The name of my configuration file is server.conf, as I have seen in /etc/openvpn, but when I execute the command sudo service openvpn@server start I obtain an error message saying that the service is unrecognized (openvpn@server: unrecognized service). If I try using the whole path (sudo service openvpn@/etc/openvpn/server start) it happens as well. If I just execute service openvpn start then it seems to work, but it is said by the manual that it actually does not start the VPN server. Is there anything that I may have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 10 months old, but since I landed here from a google search...

I don't know why this isn't working:

```
sudo service openvpn@CONFIGFILENAME <command>
```

But I know it works if you call the script directly:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn <command> CONFIGFILENAME
```

The result should be exactly the same AFAIK.